# How to make a margin smoothly transition between two percentages when the window size is adjusted

Tags: html, css, margin, viewport, viewport-units

I want to have a percentage margin around an element of 5% of the viewport's width when the viewport is small, and 15% of the width of the viewport when the viewport is larger.

I could use a media query to swap out the margin amount like this:

```
.element {
    margin: 5%;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .element {
        margin: 15%;
    }
}
```

However, I would like it to smoothly transition between the percentages when the window changes size, instead of snapping from one value to the other.

I think thought something like this could work:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .image-grid {
        margin: 1em
            calc(
                (var(--max-margin) - var(--min-margin)) * ((100vw - 800px) / (1920 - 800) +
                    var(--min-margin))
            );
    }
}
```

This should theoretically change the margin value smoothly by setting it to a percentage of the amount of change between the margins.

e.g. when viewport is small: `min-margin + [change of margin] * 0`, and when viewport is medium size: `min-margin + [change of margin] * 0.5` , and when viewport is large: min-margin + [change of margin] * 1

But it doesn't because the calc function doesn't return things like `10px / 20px` as a straight decimal eg. 0.5. Instead it would return 0.5 px. And 15% * 0.5 px is illogical and causes the margin to go back to a default of 0.

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding transition (transition: all 1s;) to your element?

Comment: @Zain That would make the switch from one percentage to the other happen smoothly over a period of time, not smoothly when adjusting the viewport width. Still better than snapping to the different value though.

Comment: In your equation the result of term `(var(--max-margin) - var(--min-margin))` needs to be unitless. As an element width `%` value yields pixels (`px`) the `calc(..)` fails as it simply does not accept a multiplification like `px * px`. FYI: you are using the *point slope form* of *linear equation* **y=mx+b** which translates in your case to: `margin = y1 * 1px + (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (100vw - x1 * 1px)` using *unitless* points low-values(x1,y1) and high-values(x2,y2) where (x,y) is (viewport width, required margin at viewport width).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following up on my comment**

- In a CSS `calc(..)` you will have to make sure that the terms in the calculation are legal. Be especially meticulous with division and multiplification!
- You have to be aware that using a size percent unit (`%`) will yield a pixel (`px`) result, as do any of the viewport size units (`vh,vw,vmin,vmax`) and their derivations.

As such your first term `(var(--max-margin) - var(--min-margin))` will yield pixel units because `%` of a size translates to a pixel result.

As the second term `((100vw - 800px) / (1920 - 800) + var(--min-margin))` also yields a value in pixel units you are multiplying pixels with pixels.

One just cannot multiply cookies with cookies.

The *point slope form* of linear equation **y=mx+b** is a perfect choice to calculate *any* size relative to the current viewport size. It is like drawing a line on an XY-graph using a low and high coordinate being **(x1,y1)** and **(x2,y2)**.

- low point (or coordinate) = required margin size at a low viewport size = *(x1,y1)*
- high point (or coordinate) = required margin size at a high viewport size = *(x2,y2)*

**The math** for the *point slope form*: `y - y1 = m(x - x1)`

- using low point **(x1,y1)** and high point **(x2,y2)**
- with substituted equation: `y = y1 + (y2 − y1) / (x2 − x1) × (x − x1)`

**In your case**

For the low point we can select any convenient viewport size and use `5%` to calculate the margin at that size. I used `400px` viewport width which yields `0.05 * 400 = 20`. Now we get low point *(x1,y1)* with value **(400,20)**

The high point is easily found as you want a margin of `15%` on viewports wider than `800px`. As `0.15 * 800 = 120` the high point *(x2,y2)* will be **(800,120)**

All we now have to do is enter the values into the above equation (with proper `px` conversion) and simplify:

- `margin = 20 * 1px + (120 - 20) / (800 - 400) * (100vw - 400 * 1px)`
- => `margin = 20px + 100 / 400 * (100vw - 400px)`
- => `margin = 20px + 0.25 * (100vw - 400px)`

You want to limit the final result between `5%` and `15%`, which will require CSS `clamp` leading to the **final result**:

- `clamp(5%, 20px + 0.25 * (100vw - 400px), 15%)`

The **snippet** shows the effect on both a clamped and unclamped version (go full page and resize the browser to see the difference).

**BTW** the *slope intercept form* (**y = mx + b**) of the final result is `25vw - 80px`.

```css
/* point slope form */
.test1 { margin: 0 clamp(5%, 20px + 0.25 * (100vw - 400px), 15%) }
.test2 { margin: 0 calc(20px + 0.25 * (100vw - 400px)) }

/* slope intercept form */
.test3 { margin: 0 clamp(5%, 25vw - 80px, 15%) }
.test4 { margin: 0 calc(25vw - 80px) }

/* just eye-candy */
*      { box-sizing: border-box; outline: 1px dashed }
body   { margin: 0; text-align: center }
.test  { background-color: Linen }
```

```html
<h3>point slope form</h3>
<div class="test test1">clamped</div>
<div class="test test2">unclampled</div>

<h3>slope intercept form</h3>
<div class="test test3">clamped</div>
<div class="test test4">unclampled</div>
```